# How to pass values from controller to view in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an application where I need to pass the value of username from a controller to a view.
i tried ViewData as given in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary.aspx

My code in controller is

```
public ActionResult Index(string UserName, string Password)
{
        ViewData["UserName"] = UserName;
        return View();
}
```

where username and password are obtained from another form.

And the code in the view is

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";  
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<%= ViewData["UserName"] %>
```

But when I run this code, the display shows <%= ViewData["UserName"] %> instead of the actual username say, for example "XYZ".

How should I display the actual UserName?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using razor syntax here but you're trying to mix it with older asp.net syntax, use

```
@ViewData["UserName"]
```

instead

Also, normally you wouldn't use the view bag to pass data to the view. Standard practice is to create a model (a standard class) with all of the bits of data your View (page) wants then pass that model to the view from your controller (return View(myModel);)

To do this you also need to declare the type of model you're using in your view

```
@model Full.Namespace.To.Your.MyModel
```

read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618479 for a basic mvc models tutorial

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you're using the Razor View Engine rather than the Web Forms View Engine.  Try the following instead:

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";   
} 
<h2>Index</h2> 
@ViewData["UserName"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'ViewBag' is a holdover from MVC2. MVC3 development should use strongly typed 'ViewModel's.