# ViewData not being passed to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to send a `String` to the controller, via AJAX, and use it in a View that will be returned by the Controller:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div id="apts"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("/Apt",{"Date": "05/29/2015"},function(response){
            $("#apts").html(response);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller.cs**

```
...
public ActionResult Apt()
{
    String date = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Date"]))
    {
        date = Request.Form["Date"];
    }
    ViewData["Date"] = date;
    return PartialView("~/Shared/_DisplaySection.cshtml");
}
```

**_DisplaySection.cshtml**

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using MySite.Models
@{
    ViewPage VP = new ViewPage();
    // error is here: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    String date = VP.ViewData["Date"].ToString();
    MySite.Models.DisplaySection DW = new DisplaySection(date); 
}

@foreach(var a in DW.data)
{
    <div>@a["name"]</div>
}
```

The error I'm getting is on `VP.ViewData["Date"].ToString()`,

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I searched for the error and found a couple of articles ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419753/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-partial-view), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753340/how-to-pass-values-from-controller-to-view-in-asp-net/8753352#8753352)). They say I need to do a null check, but the way the controller is set up, ViewData["date"] should never be null, and I'd like to keep that logic in the Controller.

Also, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979774/mvc-error-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object), but they are creating an instance of the model in the Controller, rather than the View.

Is there a better way to pass this String besides ViewData? If not, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not instance the `ViewPage`, your view already inherits from this type implicity. Try just call `ViewData` property in your view, for sample:

```
String date = ViewData["Date"].ToString();
```

AS you cna see in the [controller base class from asp.net mvc](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs), when you return a view or partialView, the controller pass the ViewData property from controller to ViewData property of View/PartialView result.

[image]